My Flutter app using Firebase gets stuck on loading screen after pressing button
My Flutter app using Firebase gets stuck on loading screen after pressing button.
button code:
TextButton(onPressed: (){
    _submit(context);
},
    child: Text("Sign In")
),

  void _submit(BuildContext context){
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if(!_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
      //Invalid
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    context.read<AuthCubit>().signUp(email: _email, username: _username, password: _password);
  }

I configured the connection settings to the Firebase according to the instructions.
There is also such a warning:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
**Warning: SDK processing. This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.**
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk

for fast playback:
sign_up_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:social_network/bloc/auth_cubit.dart';
import 'package:social_network/screens/posts_screen.dart';
import 'package:social_network/screens/sign_in_screen.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const String id = "sign up screen";


  const SignUpScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignUpScreen> createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email = "";
  String _username = "";
  String _password = "";

  late final FocusNode _passwordFocusNode;
  late final FocusNode _usernameFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();
    _usernameFocusNode = FocusNode();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _passwordFocusNode.dispose();
    _usernameFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _submit(BuildContext context){
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

    if(!_formKey.currentState!.validate()){
      //Invalid
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState!.save();
    context.read<AuthCubit>().signUp(email: _email, username: _username, password: _password);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: BlocConsumer<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
        listener: (prevState, currState){
          if(currState is AuthSignedUp){
            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(PostsScreen.id);
          }
          if(currState is AuthFailure){
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

                SnackBar(
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                    content: Text(currState.message)));
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state){
          if(state is AuthLoading){
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return SafeArea(
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18.0),
                          child: Text("Social Media App", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        // email
                        TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            labelText: "Enter you emaail",
                          ),
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_){
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_usernameFocusNode);
                          },
                          onSaved: (value){
                            _email = value!.trim();
                          },
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value!.isEmpty){
                              return "Please enter your email";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        // username
                        SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        TextFormField(
                          focusNode: _usernameFocusNode,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            labelText: "Enter you username",
                          ),
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_){
                            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
                          },
                          onSaved: (value){
                            _username = value!.trim();
                          },
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value!.isEmpty){
                              return "Please enter your username";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),
                        // password
                        SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        TextFormField(
                          focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            labelText: "Enter you password",
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_){
                            _submit(context);
                          },
                          onSaved: (value){
                            _email = value!.trim();
                          },
                          validator: (value){
                            if(value!.isEmpty){
                              return "Please enter your password";
                            }
                            if(value.length < 5){
                              return "Please enter your password more than 5 characters";
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                        ),

                        SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        TextButton(onPressed: (){
                          _submit(context);
                        },
                            child: Text("Sign Up")
                        ),
                        TextButton(onPressed: (){
                          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(SignInScreen.id);
                        },
                            child: Text("Log In")
                            //Sign In instead
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}


main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:social_network/bloc/auth_cubit.dart';
import 'package:social_network/screens/posts_screen.dart';
import 'package:social_network/screens/sign_in_screen.dart';
import 'package:social_network/screens/sign_up_screen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main()  async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AuthCubit>(
      create: (context) => AuthCubit(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: SignUpScreen(),
        routes: {
          SignInScreen.id: (context) => SignInScreen(),
          SignUpScreen.id: (context) => SignUpScreen(),
          PostsScreen.id: (context) => PostsScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


I tried to create a new user in my app but the screen gets stuck on loading.
